# Ignore comma inside #define macro call

Tags: objective-c, macros

I created a special console log function macro. It works successfully except when there's a comma in the parameter, even if it's part of another expression, i.e. not another argument. I think it's due to the fact that macros are expanded at the pre-processing stage, so the semantic analysis hasn't occurred yet to understand that the comma is not another argument. Here is what I mean:

`#define FANCY_LOG(message) [MyLogger logDebug:message withClassAndMethodName: __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ lineNumber: __LINE__];`

`+(BOOL)logDebug:(NSString *)message withClassAndMethodName:(const char *)name lineNumber:(int)lineNumber;`

These work:

```
FANCY_LOG(@"Hello world");
FANCY_LOG([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello!"]);
```

This does not work:

`FANCY_LOG([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", planet]);`

Although the comma obviously is part of the `NSString` expression, the macro interprets it as another argument, I get the following error:

`Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation`

Here's what I have tried unsuccessfully (and variants of these):

```
#define FANCY_LOG(...) [MyLogger logDebug:##__VA_ARGS___ withClassAndMethodName: __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ lineNumber: __LINE__];
#define FANCY_LOG(message) [MyLogger logDebug:#message withClassAndMethodName: __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ lineNumber: __LINE__];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing that wrong. First of all there are lots of great ready solutions so you do not have reinvent the wheel (don't remember for sure but I think `CocoaLumberjack` is best).

And your logger can look like this (I've got rusty with Objective C):

```
+(void) function:(char *)methodName
          inLine:(int)line 
            logs:(NSString *)format, ...;

 ...

#define FANCY_LOG(...) [MyLogger function: __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ \
                                   inLine: __LINE__ \
                                     logs: __VA_ARGS__]

// then usage:
FANCY_LOG(@"Hello %@!", planet);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not trying to pass multiple strings as the log argument, I'm simply trying to pass one [NSString ...] method call, but it interprets that comma as another argument (see my example above)

Comment: @JosueEspinosa what you're trying to do is impossible, the preprocessor is always going to interpret the commas as macro parameter delimiters